# I'd like to append a query string to my GitHub Page URL so that it searches my search bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, github-pages

So, GitHub Pages does not allow [.htaccess](http://rawsyntax.com/blog/blogging-on-jekyll-url-redirects/) files. I am trying to append a query string to my GitHub Page. This way someone can type: `https://cydogbrowser.com/?q=` and add their text, like `https://cydogbrowser.com/?q=flamingoes`, to search my custom bar for `flamingoes`. My custom search bar randomly rotates between search engines. My custom search bar is available here [Cydog Intensifies](https://cydogbrowser.com/CydogIntensifies.html). There is no reproducible code for this because there is nothing available as a starting point for this on the internet (based on my extensive research).

Any help on where to start or on how to solve the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you catch that `q` param from `window.location.search` (preferably using URLSearchParams) and prefill your search bar when your page is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Add this script to the end of your page body (not to the head). Or add this script in any way, just make sure the DOM is already loaded.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); //parse params
const q = params.get("q"); //get q param
document.getElementbyid("intense").value = q; //assign q value to input when loading
```